# How to send notifications using Firebase notification, android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-notifications

I am making 2 android apps. One for a customer and other for the administrator. I am using firebase as the backend service.

I want to create a Notification service such that when the user/customer clicks confirms an order, it should send a notification to another app, which is the admin's app.

Comment: You can send an HTTP request from your app to the php file which will send the notification to another app.

Comment: Is there any way without PHP, because I am not using PHP. I am having trouble in understanding firebase's notification system.

Comment: You cannot send messages directly from one device to another through Firebase Cloud Messaging. Its API requires that you pass in a so-called server key, which (as its name implies) should only be used on a server that you control. For an example of setting this up, see https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html

Comment: Yes, there are other ways to do that. I believe [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) documentation contains enough info for you.

Comment: Firebase device to device messaging without php script . Watch http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42454986/firebase-device-to-device-messaging-using-retrofit-how-do-i-get-message-id