# In Android, sending notifications to android phones via code in Firebase

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing an application that saves some data in the Firebase Database. As soon as the data is saved, I want it to be given as a notification to all the users connected to the application through code.

I couldn't understand the procedure to do so. Can anyone explain me how one can send push notifications via code in the chain as Android phone -> Firebase Database -> Notification to Android Phone with the data.

Comment: To subscribe all users to topic. As soon as the data is saved, send a device to device notification to topic. Watch http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42454986/firebase-device-to-device-messaging-using-retrofit-how-do-i-get-message-id

Answer (score -1):

it isn't Possible to solve your Problem with Firebase only. You have to create a MySQL Server and work with PHP. Maybe this Video from Filip Vujovic could help you.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LiKCEa5_Cs8

Comment: It definitely is possible without MySQL

Answer (score -1):

You can use GCM,it's simple.The GCM service handles all aspects of queueing of messages and delivery to client applications running on target devices, and it is completely free.

Comment: GCM doesn't exist anymore